# Sound sensor, Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-sensors

I want to make an test application which will be capable of recording sound of the environment and will generate a graph in android. Please someone suggest me how to capture the surroundings' sound and analyze it to detect noise or something like that. I am new in android. :)

Thank You.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the "Sound sensor" is called 'microphone' :-)

Comment: And with that said, try a Google search on 'android record sound from microphone'. You'll find quite a few results.

Comment: I don't know.. still searching.:p

Answer (score 1):

Use MediaRecorder, Luke. Or, AudioRecorder if you need more control over data, which is being recorded.

Answer (score 1):

try recording with the microphone using [AudioCapture](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html).